# Create user for Kitchen use

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, chef-infra, test-kitchen, chef-zero

I have a set of Chef scripts that make use of the 'ubuntu' user on our servers

I have now started trying to get Kitchen working on doing testing but it sets up with the 'vagrant' user so when running my scripts I get a UserIDNotFound error

Is there a way to create an 'ubuntu' user purely for use by Kitchen or else get Kitchen to do all it's work with an 'ubuntu' user rather than a 'vagrant' one?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not update the scripts to use `$USER`, which I would call a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

If your recipes need the user to exist, your recipes should include a `user` resource to create/manage the user.